# Oracle SQL academic issue. Cursors, Loops and Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

These are the requirements of the question:

Create a PL/SQL function called `findtotalcarmodels` to return the total
number of cars belonging to a particular model. The function should have a *single 
IN parameter as* `model_name`. You should then use an explicit cursor to count the 
number of cars belonging to that car model and return the final count. You must **NOT** 
use any implicit cursors, table joins, subqueries, set operators, group functions or SQL 
functions (such as COUNT) to create this function.

Now, write ONE PL/SQL anonymous block that provides a report about car details.
The full specification to create the PL/SQL anonymous block is as follows:

• Using an explicit cursor, retrieve all car registration, cost and model name 
details (registration, cost & model_name) from the `I_CAR` table.

• If the cost of the car is less than or equal to $50,000, we determine car cost 
category as “Budget Car”. If the car cost is between $50,000 and $100,000, 
the car cost category is “Standard Car”. For all other cars costing more than 
$100,000; the car cost category is “Premium Car”. Declare a local variable 
`v_carcategory as VARCHAR2(40)` to store car cost category.

• Call the function `findtotalcarmodels` to get the total number of cars 
belonging to the model name for the car and store them in a local variable 
named `v_totalcars`.

• Use an explicit cursor with a parameter that accepts car registration to find 
the most recent reservation made on the car. You will have to look at the 
`date_reserved` column from `I_BOOKING` table here. You cannot use the 
`MAX` function. Compare all the relevant dates to find the most recent one.

• Display a report showing car registration, car cost category, car model name, 
total number of cars belonging to that model and the most recent reservation 
made on that car.

• Finally, create an exception handler which fires when no rows are found. The 
exception handler should output the following message to the screen: “No 
rows found”.

Important Notes:

• You must NOT use any implicit cursors, table joins, subqueries, set operators, 
group functions or SQL functions (such as COUNT) to create the PL/SQL 
function or the PL/SQL anonymous block.

• The PL/SQL anonymous block must be ONE block only. Do NOT write a 
block to perform each task of the specification above.

This is what I have so far which I know is so far from correct it isn't even funny:

**FUNCTION:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function findtotalcarmodels
    (model_name_in IN varchar2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    counter INTEGER := 0;
    CURSOR car_count_cur IS
      SELECT model_name FROM i_car WHERE model_name = model_name_in;
        Rec_car_details car_count_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN car_count_cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH car_count_cur INTO Rec_car_details;
        EXIT WHEN car_count_cur%NOTFOUND;
        counter := counter + 1;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE car_count_cur;
    RETURN counter;
END;
```

**PL/SQL:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAP SIZE 12000 
Declare 
v_model VARCHAR2(40);
v_cost NUMBER;
v_reg VARCHAR2(10);
v_carcategory VARCHAR2(40);
v_totalcars NUMBER;
cursor carcur IS 
SELECT * FROM i_car;
v_car carcur%ROWTYPE;
Begin 
FOR v_car IN carcur LOOP
Select Registration, cost, model_name, findtotalcarmodels(model_name)
INTO v_reg, v_cost, v_model,v_totalcars
from i_car
WHERE registration = v_car.registration;
If v_cost <=50000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Budget Car';
End IF;
If v_cost BETWEEN 50000 AND 100000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Standard Car';
End IF;
If v_cost >100000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Premium Car';
End If;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Registration:'|| ' '|| v_car.registration); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cost:'|| '$' ||v_car.Cost); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Model Name:'|| ' '||v_car.model_name); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Car Category:'|| ' '||v_carcategory);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total number of Cars:'|| ' '||v_totalcars);
DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE; 
END LOOP; 
End;
```

EDIT:  The code above is where I am at now.  The only issue that remains is to get the second explicit cursor in there to return the most recent rental date.  This is the main part that has me stumped.

Comment: While I feel your pain, I can't spend the time now to flesh this out for you. And it's not clear what resources you have available, maybe a good book on PL/SQL, else there are numerous oracle doc and training that should give big hints on this. I would divide and conquer: find the easiest requirement and get that to work and then continue from there. Again divide and conquer, even with your questions here on S.O. making a smaller test case that solves one problem at a time. This question is a mouthful, except to a journeyman coder, so break it up! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shellter.  Yeah I will take a DaC approach.  What is tripping me up is the requirement for explicit cursors.  Lol my gosh this is a headache.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the cursor in the function looks like an explicit cursor (as does the other one). I know there are frustrating syntax issues between regular SQL and PL/SQL, like the placement of closing ';' chars (which I can't rely define or explain right now). Are you getting basic stuff to work? Can you do a hello world in PL/SQL? Again, posting a focused question is likely to get  you speedy results. Good luck.

Comment: I have edited my question to show my current progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below explicit cursor to get the most recent rental date by just comparing that there does not exist a data_reserved which is greater than the recent data_reserved

```
CURSOR c1(v_car_registration VARCHAR2) IS 
  SELECT * from i_booking a
  WHERE a.registration=v_car_registration
  and not exists(select 1 from i_booking b 
  where b.registration=v_car_registration
  and b.date_reserved > a.date_reserved);
```

and you can call the explicit cursor where l_car_registration is the variable passed to the cursor like the below

```
FOR rec in c1(l_car_registration)
LOOP
--code here 
END LOOP;
```

EDIT1:-to find the recent date using PLSQL

```
DECLARE
l_max_date DATE:=TO_DATE(1, 'J');--minimum date that can be entered in oracle database
cursor carcur IS 
SELECT * FROM i_car;
CURSOR c1(v_car_registration VARCHAR2) IS 
  SELECT * from i_booking a
  WHERE a.registration=v_car_registration;
 BEGIN
 For car_rec in carcur 
 LOOP
 l_max_date:=TO_DATE(1, 'J');
  for rec in c1(car_rec.registration)
  loop
   IF rec.date_reserved > l_max_date 
   then
    l_max_date:=rec.date_reserved ;
   end IF;
  end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line('car_registration--'||car_rec.registration||'the recent date--'||l_max_date);
 END LOOP;
 end;
```

Comment: I am getting: ERROR at line 6: 
ORA-06550: line 6, column 9: 
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "A"."CAR_REGISTRATION": invalid identifier 
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3: 
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 
ORA-06550: line 10, column 34: 
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'REC' use is invalid 
ORA-06550: line 10, column 2: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Car registration is my assumption of the column name, kindly use my example with the actual table and column name

Comment: edited the answer with actual column and table provided on the question

Comment: Thanks psaraj12.  Is there a way to get this to show the dates for all registrations rather than just the one give in l_car_registration VARCHAR2(1000):='RRRRXXXX123';?  For example could you use another cursor to get a parameter and place that parameter into a cursor?  If so, how?  Also, I am not allowed to use the GREATEST function.

Comment: Splunk,i have updated the answer

Comment: car_rec and rec are like record for the respective cursors using which you can access all the columns in the Cursor.

Comment: Thanks psaraj12, I really appreciate your efforts.  However the dates it is returning are incorrect.  It is showing only 01/OCT/12 and 20/OCT/12.

Comment: just check how many different car registration are there and what is the recent date of each of them using the query SELECT b.registration,a.date_reserved from i_booking a,i_car b
  WHERE a.registration=b.registration
  and not exists(select 1 from i_booking c
  where c.registration=a.registration
  and c.date_reserved > a.date_reserved);

Comment: Yep the registrations look good, however the dates are wrong produced by the cursor.

Comment: updated the answer for each registration i need to initialize the value of max date

Comment: psaraj12 thank you so much for your help.  You have taught me a lot.

Comment: Splunk thanks,Programming is difficult and it is always good to help each others